# passing ruby parameters as query string in Jquery ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

I am using jquery draggable and droppable functions. SO when an element is dropped an ajax call would be initiated passing parameters as query string. I know how to pass query string. But i need to do some conditional checking in query string parameters. I am not sure how it can be done. Please find my code below.

```
jQuery('#<%= qtr %>').droppable({
    hoverclass: 'e_high',
    accept: function(elm) {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('<%=name%>_edit'))
            return true;
        },
        drop: function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/sections/reorder?site_id=<%=@site.id%>&page=<%=@page%>?<%=@page.id%>:nil&ref_id=<%=section.id%>&name=<%=name%>'
```

Is the above method of passing query string correct. I am getting a No method error. Nil object. When i checked the terminal the params are Parameters: `{"page"=>"", "site_id"=>"11650ecf55668fed9e7a624c93adcba2"}`

Comment: the question is not clear. About the nil method problem, probably a     @variable is not defined. What kind of conditional you want to write? my advice: don't mix ruby and JS code. Use pure-JS funcions (in .js files) that you call from partials (always: argument.to_json in the Ruby arguments)

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your ternary question mark and colon are in the wrong place, they should be *inside* the ERB delimiters. You'd be better off use the `data` option for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) here; this will not only be cleaner but it will keep you from using GET parameters in a POST request. And you should be escaping your values for using in JavaScript with [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript). Try it like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/sections/reorder',
    data: {
        site_id: '<%= j(@site.id) %>',
        page: '<%= j(@page ? @page.id : '') %>',
        ref_id: '%<= j(section.id) %>',
        name: '%<= j(name) %>'
    },
    //...
```

This assumes of course that `section` and `name` are available in ERB as Ruby variables rather than client-side JavaScript variables.

And if for some reason you must use a GET query string with a POST request, then you'd want something like this:

```
url: '/sections/reorder?site_id=<%= j(@site.id) %>&page=<%= j(@page ? @page.id : '') %>&ref_id=<%= j(section.id) %>&name=<%= j(name) %>'
```